# Knockout parent-child lazy load with mapping plugin & KoGrid

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0, kogrid

**Set up:**
In my viewmodel, I have an observable array of item built from JSON (it only has name and ID) called "items".  I also have an observable for just the selected item (it has the full details for the item) called "selecteditem".  When you click an item from the "items" list, it should populate "selecteditem", which will fill "itemdetails" with the full details via another JSON reply, allow you to edit them, and save the changes.

**Progress:**
The clicking of the grid is working correct, and it's getting the correct VendorID and passing that along to the query string as /api/vendor/14 if I click vendor 14.

**Issue:**
How do update JUST the selecteditem portion of my viewmodel with the 2nd ajax call (fired when you click one of the items).

KoGrid HTML:

```
             <div class="gridContainer">
                <div data-bind="koGrid: { 
                    data: items, 
                    autogenerateColumns: false,
                    isMultiSelect: false,
                    displaySelectionCheckbox: false,
                    selectedItem: selecteditem,
                    columnDefs: [
                        { field: 'VendorID', displayName: 'Vendor ID' },
                        { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Vendor Name' }
                    ]}">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Child HTML (just a few fields now for testing):

```
            <div data-bind="foreach: itemdetails">
                <span data-bind="text: BusinessContactName"></span><br />
                <span data-bind="text: BusinessContactTitle"></span>
            </div>
```

Javascript:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var API_URL = "/api/vendor/";

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: API_URL,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    /* View Model */
                    window.viewModel = {
                        items: ko.mapping.fromJS(data),
                        selecteditem: ko.observable(),
                        itemdetails: ko.observable()
                    };

                    /* Get Selected Item */
                    window.viewModel.selecteditem.subscribe(function (newValue) {
                        if (newValue) {
                            var param = newValue.VendorID();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'GET',
                                url: API_URL + param,
                                dataType: 'json',
                                success: function (data2) {
                                    //What to do here??
                                    window.viewModel.itemdetails = ko.mapping.fromJS(data2);
                                    //This shows the correct value
                                    alert(window.viewModel.itemdetails.BusinessContactName());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks like the setting of your viewModels itemdetails is incorrect.

instead of window.viewModel.itemdetails = ko.mapping.fromJS(data2);

use window.viewModel.itemdetails(ko.mapping.fromJS(data2));